# What's the hardest thing in Italian: again, but data-based

Tags: resources

[This question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/whats-if-any-the-hardest-thing-to-learn-in-italian-for-foreigners) asks "what's the hardest thing to learn in Italian for foreigners", but it is phrased as a request for opinions, and so it has (correctly, in my view) been closed.

However, that question can be answered more scientifically: foreign learners take Italian tests and quizzes all the time, and it should be possible to use some statistics to tell (for instance) if questions on the usage of subjunctive have a higher error rate than questions on the usage of pronouns.

Are there any statistical analyses of this kind? What is, truly, the hardest thing to learn in Italian?

Comment: I think it is going to be strongly dependent on the source language. It is well documented that the "hardness" of a language varies according to the native tongue of the learner, I don't see why it should be different for individual features. We might be able to find good data for English speakers

Comment: As a statistician, I had to give this a +1. If anybody has any available data, I would be more than happy to thoroughly analyze it and see if there is anything that really gives students a hard time regardless of their native language. Sorry for the noisy comment.